# Xcode6 beta SourceKitService error

Tags: xcode6, swift

I'm running lastest Mavenricks with Xcode 5.1.1

I've downloaded Xcode 6 beta from apple and this message shows up constantly. Thus, I can barely write any code because code completion disabled.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

[image]

Comment: @VigneshKumar [we already have too many tags for Swift, why are you creating **ANOTHER**!?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258076/168868)  Please go back and correct your tagging.

Comment: Looks like a mod made it a synonym.  Regardless, **please** be more careful in the future...

Comment: possible duplicate of [SourceKitService Terminated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006206/sourcekitservice-terminated)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your project named `Swift`? With seeing that message, build would be failed too with message: `<unknown>:0: error: module name "Swift" is reserved for the standard library`. Try using another project name such as `SwiftTest`. It would work.

(Duplicated: [SourceKitService Terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006206/sourcekitservice-terminated/24009979#24009979))

Answer (score 1):

Try For it

**

> There is a bug in the Swift compiler / indexer. Some line or lines in
>   your code is giving it difficulty. You will have to edit your code
>   with some other text editor to comment out the offending line(s)
>   before you will be able to open that project with Xcode. If you have
>   no clue what the problem is, comment out all your code. Once you have
>   the project open, you can start bringing back code little by little
>   until the rise in CPU activity tells you that you've found the
>   problem.

**