# SourceKitService Terminated with no Xcode warning or errors

Tags: ios, swift, sourcekitservice

I was spacing out while starting a new project to port one of my Obj-C/SpriteKit apps over to Swift and started to add a touch for loop within touchesMoved. My mistake, but the weird issue is that I get "SourceKitService Terminated" and Xcode completely bugs out.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

    }
}
```

Specifically, this happens the moment I begin to type "touches" in the for loop. Entering "for touch: AnyObject in" everything is still fine. As soon as I continue to type "touches"... SourceKitService Terminated.

I get that this should be an error, but why is Xcode completely freaking out because of this?

Comment: Rule of thumb: If the editor freaks out, it's a bug in the editor. Please report it. :)

Comment: This is a well known bug of the software in a beta stage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SourceKitService Terminated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006206/sourcekitservice-terminated)

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error so the SourceKitService is throwing up. It worked for me when I did

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    for touch : AnyObject in touches.allObjects{
        print(touch)

    }
}
```

Not sure if this fixes your issue. Please be kind we're all swift newbs :)

Comment: Thanks dude. The work around solved the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with xcode 6 beta 6.  I finally changed the iOS Deployment Target from 7.0 to 7.1 and my problem went away!