# How to use detailTextLabel when initializing cell in code?

Tags: swift2, uitableview

I don't have a prototype cell in IB.  I'm initializing the cell in code.

```
let mycell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
mycell.textLabel!.text = "main text"
mycell.detailTextLabel!.text = "test"
```

The `mycell.textLabel!.text` call works fine.  But the `mycell.detailTextLabel!.text` call crashes the app because `mycell.detailTextLabel` is nil.  Is there something else I need to do for that part to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem - this helped.

[How to Set UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle and dequeueReusableCell in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062285/how-to-set-uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-and-dequeuereusablecell-in-swift)

Use something like:

```
cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,
                reuseIdentifier: "identifier")
```

Comment: If you type only the dot, Subtitle doesn't appear in the hints.  You have to type out UITableViewCellStyle then dot and it is there.  Do you know why?

Comment: I don't, but I ran into this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025110/autocomplete-for-leading-dot-doesnt-work-in-swift