# Xcode does not provide any suggestion when select swift language

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am just trying to learn swift. When i type `@`, XCode doesn't give any suggestion. I want to write `@IBAction, @IBOutlet` etc. If i write that, XCode  does not show any error and it's work fine. If it's work then, why Xcode does not show any suggestion?  I am using  XCode 6.2 and iOS 8.2 . Please tell me how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Did you select Objective-C or Swift when creating the project / file ?

Comment: i have selected Swift

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 with Swift super slow typing and autocompletion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948024/xcode-6-with-swift-super-slow-typing-and-autocompletion)

Comment: Swift autocompletion is [really slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948024/xcode-6-with-swift-super-slow-typing-and-autocompletion). File a radar if you want it fixed...

Comment: If its not showing you suggestion, you can try ctrl+space to show suggestions

Comment: Autocompletion is not only slow, it often simply fails. Restart XCode (and eventually clearing cashes) improves the situation for a while. But just for a while.