# XCode provides limited suggestions after dot notation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autocomplete

after a dot notation xcode provides some suggestions however it is very limited. For example, in the following picture 1, I have sender.title. I would like xcode to provide suggestions that not only start with title but also contatin the word title in it. in this case, I was looking for sender.currentTitle, but I couldn't see it since xcode only provides suggestions that start with title.

[image]

Comment: OK. Do you have a question about something? I'm feeling like you want to send a feature request to Apple rather.

Comment: sorry, my question is how do I set xcode to provide more suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using (there is `println` from Swift 1.2 in your code) ?

Comment: I am using xcode 6.4 and swift 1.2

Comment: That is quite old. As far as I remember, the "improved autocompletion" was introduced with Xcode 8.

Comment: I see, I will update it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Using swift 3.0, xcode8.1 and autocomplete has a good list to get the right option also any time if you can't see autosuggestion you can press `esc` or `control+comma`(for list) to get the pop up again, however I am new to swift and love this programming language !!

Since you are using Xcode 6, so it might possible This answer can help you [StackoverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948024/xcode-6-with-swift-super-slow-typing-and-autocompletion)

**-Cheers**

Comment: thanks for the reply, after updating xcode, it started working