# Slow autocomplete in Xcode 8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I recently got a 2016 nTB MBP. I started Obj-C in Xcode 8 a few days ago.

What I noticed, that autocomplete is really useful but it's incredibly slow. Even inside an extremely simple class (fractions, just for practice), the delay is very annoying when typing.

Is this normal or it should be smooth?

I removed it with AppCleaner and reinstalled it but it's just the same.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Xcode. I am just grateful IF autocompletion is working. Because often — for reasons unknown to me — it doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 with Swift super slow typing and autocompletion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948024/xcode-6-with-swift-super-slow-typing-and-autocompletion)

Comment: This was definitely not the case when I was working with Objective C. However, for Swift, it is almost unusable with the autocompletion.

Comment: @daspianist Sad it's true, objc highlighting and autocompletion is way faster.

Answer (score 14):

Tame the beast with:

Xcode | Preferences | General > Uncheck "Show live issues"

BTW None of the answers in the "Possible duplicate" above fixed this for me.

Comment: same behaviour. I would like to know what are the spcs of your machine. I have I5 2014 macbook pro with 8ram ddr3 ssd 128, 2.6Ghz

Comment: @Marlhex 2015 MBP / i7 2.5Ghz / 16GB / 512GB SSD

Comment: we need to get 3.0Ghz at least bro there is second hand MBP on facebook like mine is $450 CAD and I bought it for 750 haha! Yours will be cool little faster with those 16GB. I'm looking for the iMac so I can get 64GB. but I still want 3.5Ghz+

Answer (score 4):

The new Xcode 9 Beta is immeasurably faster for me and solved the annoying editing delays from having autocomplete and live issues turned on.

Not sure if you can deploy to the App Store with beta Xcode, but I'm going to develop in beta and open the normal Xcode to deploy.