# NSFileManager leads to SourceKit Service Terminated

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

It's totally confusing on using this line

```
 var docContents : NSArray! = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(archieveDirectoryPath,error: 
 &err)
```

I get the alert like **SourceKit Service Terminated Editor Functionality temporary limited** continuously, and gone swift coding style. But When I comment this line, all are disappeared.

Any one experienced this or is this a common error?

**Note:** I've tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006206/sourcekitservice-terminated)'s answer, But won't work. Just comment that line, it gets work. But I need that line. I'm using **Xcode-6-beta-2**

Comment: It's *beta* of *Xcode*, crashes/bugs are to be expected.

Comment: Ya Correct. But there may be workaround for those bugs. I'm looking for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed by below code. I think, it may common error. Just replace `!` with `?` symbol.

```
var docContents : NSArray? = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(archieveDirectoryPath,error: 
 &err)
```

But I didn't see any docs related  `how this happen`. If anybody know, let me know. I think, this may temporary workaround.