# "SourceKitService Terminated" when working in multiple Swift projects?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode6, sourcekitservice

I'm trying to set up a CocoaTouch Framework project for iOS using Swift, but any time I add another project it freaks out and throws a "SourceKitService Terminated" error and the editor window goes black and white.

Here's what I'm able to do to reproduce the problem in XCode 6 Beta 4:

- Create a new "CocoaTouch Framework" for iOS, named "Testing" with the organization "Test" (I've tried it with other names/organizations, it doesn't seem to be related to that).
- Create a new Swift file within the "Testing" folder called "File.swift". I didn't add any code besides the "import Foundation" that the template comes with
- Create another "CocoaTouch Framework" project, leaving all the defaults but changing the name to "TestTwo."
- Add a "File.swift" file to the TestTwo folder, then start typing "class" or something else underneath "import Foundation".
- The editor crashes with a "SourceKitService Terminated" error

Can anyone else reproduce this, or is it something wrong with my installation? I've tried reinstalling, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Thanks,

Matthew

Comment: [File a bug](http://bugreporter.apple.com). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006206/sourcekitservice-terminated

Comment: The Swift parser/REPL chokes on certain errors. It's a bug.

Comment: OK, I'll file one. I saw the other question, but seeing as though this was something that was very specific to cause I thought I'd post another in case anyone else had a fix for this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about problems with a beta toolset

Answer (score 0):

**Dear Matthew**

I had the same problem although the problem is in your code , I know Xcode 6 beta is not very polished but this is the very simple code I wrote for this project:

override func override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

```
    }
}
```

My brand new iMac freaked out. So this is probably not the best answer although I hope it helps.
You have probable tried doing a new file but the problem is in that code somewhat . If I were you I would take the override functions first and see what happens because they are what have been causing trouble on my part.

Hope it helps,

Jules Olds

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This answer does **not** appear to answer the orginal question.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer, but the problem was not with my code. I hadn't added any code other than what was in there by default with the template and it still broke.