# Swift println() not showing autocomplete options while writing code

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

When I am trying to print using `println()` function it is not showing autocomplete parameter list in swift. Is there any problem in my Xcode?

Comment: just restart xcode and check

Comment: I restarted xcode as well as my mac, but still not working. I am using xcode6.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 Swift code completion not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25883905/456814).

Comment: Bob Thanks for marking duplicate so early

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I found the reason for this....
As Dhruv mentioned, it only accepts string argument. So we need to convert object to string inline println() function.

For example:

we have integer defined as 
 **var age:Int = 24**

then we can print this as

**println("\(age)")**

In this case we will get autocomplete option. 
On other hand **println(age)** will print same result as above.

Answer (score 37):

Delete `user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and delete the data of folder(Derive data) and restart Xcode. Should work. If doesn't, restart mac after doing this.

> **Note:** for Xcode 11.7 and maybe later, use the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` path.

Comment: Then, reinstall xcode. I always keep a installer file with me for such emergency purposes. Good luck :)

Comment: Here's a link I found that might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783478/xcode-autocomplete-stopped-working

Comment: Then you are experiencing NO PROBLEM! There is no autocomplete for println(). Congrats!

Comment: Because I think it's just too obvious. println() just takes a string. Any other datatype have to be converted to string in order to use them or otherwise are automatically converted.

Comment: Then according to your above comment , var which is of string type should be available in autocomplete list. isn't so?

Comment: Just checked. Doesn't show variable in autocomplete

Comment: is it documented anywhere ?

Comment: Works for me, thank you, I did not even have to restart xCode.

Answer (score 2):

1. Press cmd + K in your Xcode;
2. Do context-click on Xcode -> Quit, and **the same for Simulator**.
3. Open the project again;
4. **If still doesn't work, you don't need to restart your mac**. Write "Int." or some other system type, but not yours that you have issue with and voila!