# Source kit service crashed error whenever i start a project with core data involved

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift, crash

I am new to iOS programming and recently started to dabble in core data. However when i create my project in Xcode and click on the editor I would receive a crash report as shown in the URL below:

[SourceKit Service Crash Error Screenshot](http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah58/Wesley_Ow/Sourcekitcrashed_zpsca1ecb29.png)

I have tried reinstalling Xcode and it does not solve the problem.

any advice on what i should do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006206/sourcekitservice-terminated

Comment: @Vitaliy1 hey thanks for the link, at first i thought these 2 errors were unrelated but i guess they are the same after all. Apparently deleting the contents of my derived data file has fixed it. not sure whether the error will recur.