# Choose what information Parse saves to User class from Facebook login

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to get more information than just a Facebook user's id when they log in. I am using **Parse** to create users, and I would like to store their first and last name, as well as email. I read that this information is part of the `public_profile` but only the Facebook id is stored. Below is the code that I'm using when the user presses the "Log in with Facebook" button.

This is probably similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875716/swift-and-parse-and-xcode-problems) question, but any help would be greatly appreciated. This has nothing to do with accessing Facebook's api, I'm looking for help with Parse.

```
    // login with Facebook button
@IBAction func FBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    // permissions for Facebook login
    let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "first_name"]

    // call Facebook log in when button is pressed
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user == nil {
            NSLog("User cancelled the Facebook login.")
        } else if user.isNew {
            NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook.")
        } else {
            NSLog("User logged in through Facebook.")
        }
    })  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not see this when I was searching around. I will attempt it with that post.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is not a dupe.  It uses a different language, API and retrieves different data fields than @atwalsh04 is looking for.

Comment: @JasonMArcher is correct. I have edited the question to explain I am looking for help with Parse Users and the swift language.